# Zimbra zcs on ubuntu 12.04 x86

Tags: zimbra

I would like to know hot to install Zimbra on ubuntu 12.04 x86 as I get the error below when I try to install  it.

"Found zimbra-core
Error: attempting to install x86_64 packages on a i386 OS.
Exiting..."

Someone please help me

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message said, you tried to install 64-bit software on a 32-bit Linux distribution.

To resolve the issue, first reinstall with 64-bit Ubuntu. Then try installing Zimbra.

Comment: my computer does not have a 32 bit and I would like to have ubuntu 12.04 running on it.

Comment: @pnanvuma - As I'm certain you read in our help pages when you came here this site is for professional sysadmins, you are very clearly not one, learn some basics about computers before coming to a professional IT site again and don't post here until then.

Comment: My apologies.I meant to say, in my previous comment, that my computer has a 32-bit processor and so can only have a 32-bit ubuntu version 12.04 on it. yet zimbra requires a 64-bit ubuntu 12.04 installation. I am wondering if there is a workaround for this.

Comment: Buy a computer that was made in the last ten years.

Comment: @Michael, fair enough but I was trying to work with what I have.Thanks though